# How do you declare multiple function pointers in a single line without typedeffing?

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

More of a matter of curiosity than anything.  Basically I want to know if it's possible to declare multiple function pointers in a line,  something like:

```
int a = 1, b = 2;
```

With function pointers? Without having to resort to `typedef`.

I've tried `void (*foo = NULL, *bar = NULL)(int)`.  Unsurprisingly, this didn't work.

Comment: While I guessed correctly, I have to say I've never seen (for good reason) or tried this before.

Comment: powerful in the obfuscated code world... just need a couple of #def's to represent them as 6 underscores and you are in business!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try as follows:

```
void (*a)(int), (*b)(int);

void test(int n)
{
    printf("%d\n", n);
}
int main()
{
    a = NULL;
    a = test;
    a(1);
    b = test;
    b(2);
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Another form is array of function pointers:

```
void (*fun[2])(int) = {NULL, NULL};

void test(int n)
{
    printf("%d\n",n);
}
int main()
{
    fun[0] = NULL;
    fun[0] = test;
    fun[0](1);
    fun[1] = test;
    fun[1](2);
}
```

Comment: Yes write your declarations after `test(){}` as [`void (*a)(int) = test, (*b)(int) = test;`](http://codepad.org/XkYPuwer)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I think the second form I just edited is more likely the one what R.D. want

Comment: may be, But Excellent response,  Excellent answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
void (*foo)(int) = NULL, (*bar)(int) = NULL;
```

or as Grijesh says:

```
int main(void) {
    int a[5], b[55];
    int (*aa)[5] = &a, (*bb)[55] = &b;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you might like to add similarly pointer to array declaration can be done: `int (*a)[5], (*b)[7];` here is a [codepade link](http://codepad.org/ODgCNXdq)